# Looping in HashMap on Jsp

Tags: hashmap

i am using spring with hibernate. In my controller i am calling a method which is returning an HashMap as follows:

```
public HashMap<String,Object> getJobs() {
        ArrayList<com.jobs.admin.data.Job> jobs= new ArrayList<com.jobs.admin.data.Job>();
        ArrayList <com.jobs.admin.data.Company> companies=new ArrayList<com.jobs.admin.data.Company>();
        HashMap<String,Object> mappedData= new HashMap<String,Object>();
        db_session= HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            transaction= db_session.beginTransaction();
            Iterator iterator =  db_session.createQuery("from Job as job inner join job.jobCompany as company").list().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                Object[] data = (Object[]) iterator.next();
                jobs.add((com.jobs.admin.data.Job)data[0]);
                companies.add((com.jobs.admin.data.Company) data[1]);
            }
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            db_session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("got it");
        mappedData.put("jobs", jobs);
        mappedData.put("companies", companies);
        return mappedData;
    }
```

I am calling above method in Spring controller as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/viewJobs.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showViewJobs(ModelMap model)
    {
        HashMap mappdeData= jobImpl.getJobs();
        model.addAttribute("jobs",mappdeData);
        return "/admin/viewJobs";
    }
```

Now my question is that i am returning a hash map to my jsp , this hash map contains two array list. On jsp how can i make loop for getting values in this hash map. ?

Comment: any results for this question?